# How to count cumulative unique values by group?

Tags: python, pandas, group

I wonder how to count accumulative unique values by groups in python?

Below is the dataframe example:

| Group | Year | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1998 | red |
| A | 1998 | blue |
| A | 2002 | red |
| A | 2005 | blue |
| A | 2008 | blue |
| A | 2008 | yello |
| B | 1998 | red |
| B | 2001 | red |
| B | 2003 | red |
| C | 1996 | red |
| C | 2002 | orange |
| C | 2002 | red |
| C | 2012 | blue |
| C | 2012 | yello |

I need to create a new column by Column "Group". The value of this new column should be the accumulative unique values of Column "Type", accumulating by Column "Year".

Below is the dataframe I want.
For example:
(1)For Group A and in year 1998, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998, and there are two unique values of Type: red and blue.
(2)For Group A and in year 2002, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998 and 2002, and there are also two unique values of Type: red and blue.
(3)For Group A and in year 2008, I want to count the unique value of Type in year 1998, 2002, 2005, and 2008, and there are three unique values of Type: red, blue, and yellow.

| Group | Year | Type | Want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1998 | red | 2 |
| A | 1998 | blue | 2 |
| A | 2002 | red | 2 |
| A | 2005 | blue | 2 |
| A | 2008 | blue | 3 |
| A | 2008 | yello | 3 |
| B | 1998 | red | 1 |
| B | 2001 | red | 1 |
| B | 2003 | red | 1 |
| C | 1996 | red | 1 |
| C | 2002 | orange | 2 |
| C | 2002 | red | 2 |
| C | 2012 | blue | 4 |
| C | 2012 | yello | 4 |

One more thing about this dataframe: not all groups have values in the same years. For example, group A has two values in year 1998 and 2008, one value in year 2002 and 2005. Group B has values in year 1998, 2001, and 2003.

I wonder how to address this problem. Your great help means a lot to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For each `Group`:

Append a new column `Want` that has the values like you want:

```py
def f(df):
    want = df.groupby('Year')['Type'].agg(list).cumsum().apply(set).apply(len)
    want.name = 'Want'
    return df.merge(want, on='Year')

df.groupby('Group', group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result:**

```py
   Group  Year    Type  Want
0      A  1998     red     2
1      A  1998    blue     2
2      A  2002     red     2
3      A  2005    blue     2
4      A  2008    blue     3
5      A  2008   yello     3
6      B  1998     red     1
7      B  2001     red     1
8      B  2003     red     1
9      C  1996     red     1
10     C  2002  orange     2
11     C  2002     red     2
12     C  2012    blue     4
13     C  2012   yello     4
```

> **Notes:**
>
> - I think the use of `.merge` here is efficient.
> - You can also use 1 `.apply` inside `f` instead of 2 chained ones to improve efficiency: `.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))`